# Selecting multiple items in excel pivot filter. But I don't want to be specific while mentioning the items in code. Is there any better way than this?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, wildcard

Sub CreatePivot()
Dim PItem as PivotItem
Dim PTable as PivotTable

```
    For Each PItem in PTable.PivotFields("Employee_Name").PivotItems
            If PItem.Name Like "*XXX*" Or PItem.Name Like "*YYY*" Or PItem.Name Like "*ZZZ*"
                    PItem.Visible = True
            Else
                    PItem.Visible = False
            End If
    Next PItem
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

### Pivot Table Sub

- The following might give you some ideas (not tested).
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createPivotTEST()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const ptName As String = "Pivottable1"
    Const pfName As String = "Employee_Name"
    Const CriteriaList As String = "XXX,YYY,ZZZ"

    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim pTable As PivotTable: Set pTable = ws.PivotTables(ptName)
    Dim pField As PivotField: Set pField = pTable.PivotFields(pfName)

    CreatePivot pField, Criteria

End Sub

Sub CreatePivot(ByVal pField As PivotField, ByVal Criteria As Variant)
    
    Dim cLower As Long: cLower = LBound(Criteria)
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(Criteria)
    
    Dim pItem As PivotItem
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each pItem In pField.PivotItems
        For n = 0 To cUpper
            If pItem.Name Like "*" & Criteria(n) & "*" Then
                If Not pItem.Visible Then
                    pItem.Visible = True
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
        If n > cUpper Then
            If pItem.Visible Then
                pItem.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Next pItem

End Sub
```